# How to change the color of a magic comment

Tags: texstudio, color-profile, magic-comment

In TeXStudio you can have magic comments: `% !TeX`. I want to change their foreground color, but can't find that option in the `Syntax Highlighting` tab in the configuration options.

How can I change that color?

Answer (score 3):

<s>That setting is currently not configurable by the user. Will be fixed in the next release.</s>

This is included since version 2.10.0:

```
Options -> Syntax Highlighting -> Basic Highlighting -> magicComment
```

Comment: Is there any progress?

Comment: This in included since version 2.10.0: `Options -> Syntax Highlighting -> Basic Highlighting -> magicComment`